# Installing a python service with --username xxx --password xxxx

Tags: python, service, installation

I have a python service installed and working on a local machine but the service I am writing needs to access another machine.  It needs to be associated with a username and password. When I try `myservice.py --username xxx --password yyy --startup auto install` I get an error message

```
Installing service apdm_upLoader
Error installing service: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified
. (1057)
```

Ideas would sure be appreciated.
Scott

Comment: Please, specify which python service did you install. Are you sure your username and password is the right one? (maybe some typo...)

Comment: You didnt tell us anything about what you are using, or the operating system, or anything about this specific 'service'. And then you posted your own answer. Sounds like you were just thinking out load on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, if you don't have a domain then you should use .\username.  I discovered this by going to my computer / manage / services.  First I had to do a simple install of the process which works fine.  Then in the services pane I double clicked my python process and there was a really nice gui to do all the management I needed to do.

Hope this helps someone.
Scott

Comment: This doesnt help any one because no one knows what you were even using.